# Is it possible to paginate COLUMNs of a Smart-table

Tags: angularjs, pagination, smart-table

I am creating a visual table configurator, user defines column, I would like to show 6 columns at a time and user can see the next 6 column using pagination UI

Answer (score 0):

smart-table does not come with this functionality built in, however as you control the markup, it is possible implement this yourself. Consider the following markup (pseudo code):

```
<table st-table="data">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="col in displayedColumns" st-sort="col.property">{{col.title}}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td ng-repeat="col in displayedColumns">
            {{row[col.property]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now we can feed the object with the data and displayedColumn collections with the desired data:

```
$scope.data = [
    { a: 'some stuff', b: 'other stuff', c: 123, d: 'I am text' },
    { a: 'next object', b: undefined, c: 999, d: 'Written in stone' },
    { a: 'Cool', b: 'table', c: 13.2354, d: 'I am text' }
];

$scope.displayedColumns = [
    { property: 'a', title: 'The A column' },
    { property: 'b', title: 'The B column' }
];
```

The table will now display the table with only the columns a and b. If you then have a way of manipulating the displayedColumns to say show columns c and d, this will be reflected in grid.

Hope this solves your use case.